# The boundary $\partial A$ is closed in a topological space $X$. (slight proof explanation)

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> The boundary $\partial A$ is closed in a topological space $X$.

I am trying to show that $A\setminus \partial A$ and $A^{c}\setminus \partial A$ are open, since $X\setminus \partial A=(A\setminus \partial A)\cup (A^{c}\setminus \partial A)$.

In my professor's notes, it states that if $x\in A\setminus \partial A$, then there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U\cap A^{c}=\emptyset$. Then it states that $U\cap \partial A=\emptyset$ follows.

Can someone please explain the reason $U\cap \partial A=\emptyset$? I cannot connect the definition of the boundary set and the fact that $U\cap A^{c}=\emptyset$. Much appreciated!

Comment: An open set that intersects the boundary of $A$ necessarily intersects the complement of $A$: points on the boundary are in the closure of the complement of $A$.

Comment: $U$ is open, so if $y \in \partial A$ is in $U$, then a small ball $B(y,\epsilon) \subset U$, some $\epsilon > 0$. But this ball must contain an element in $A^\complement$, contradicting that $U \cap A^\complement = \emptyset$.

Comment: There's a much easier way to show this, depending on how you define the boundary. If it is closure minus interior, then it is the intersection of two closed sets and is therefore closed.

Comment: @bounceback Thank you, your comment was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, $\partial A$ is the set of all points $y \in X$ such that for any open set $V$ containing $y$ we have $V \cap A \neq \varnothing$ and $V \cap A^\textsf{c} \neq \varnothing$. So, for $y \in (\partial A)^\textsf{c}$ there exists an open set $V_0$ containing $y$ such that $$\textrm{$V_0 \cap A = \varnothing \ $ or $\ V_0 \cap A^\textsf{c} = \varnothing$.}$$

Hence, for $x \in A \setminus \partial A = A \cap (\partial A)^\textsf{c}$ there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U \cap A = \varnothing$ or $U \cap A^\textsf{c} = \varnothing$, but the case $U \cap A = \varnothing$ is impossible since $x \in U \cap A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$.
The boundary of $A$, $\partial{A}$, can be expressed as $\overline{A}\backslash intA$.

As $\partial{A}$ is the intersection of closed sets, it is therefore closed.

Answer (score 0):

$\partial A$ is the set of $x$ such that all neighbourhoods of $x$ intersect $A$ and $A^\complement$.

So if $x \notin \partial A$ this means that one of two things must be true:

1. $x$ has a neighbourhood $U$ that misses $A$, and this means that $x \in \operatorname{int}(A^\complement)$ as $x \in U \subseteq A^\complement$.
2. $x$ has a neighbourhood $U$ that misses $A^\complement$, and this means that $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$ as $x \in U \subseteq A$.

It's also clear that the other inclusions also hold and so

$$X\setminus \partial A = \operatorname{int}(A^\complement) \cup \operatorname{int}(A)$$ and so its complement is open and $\partial A$ is closed.

Another way to see closedness is to convince yourself that $$\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^\complement}$$ from the definition as well.